# Вводные слова и выражения

Tags: вводные-слова

Являются ли здесь "в большей степени" и "в лучшем случае" вводными?

Конечно, у нас есть отдельные примеры создания продуктов мирового уровня, но это, скорее, исключение из правила, это то, что создано не «благодаря», а в большей степени «вопреки».

И результат будет не через два-три года, а в лучшем случае через 15 лет.

Comment: Нет, по-моему.  И "в большей степени", и "в лучшем случае" - фразеологизм, используемый в качестве обстоятельства.  Вводные слова можно изъять из предложения без изменения его смысла ("впрочем", "правда", "итак").  Эти нельзя, похоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ОТВЕТ

(1) И результат будет не через два-три года, а в лучшем случае через 15 лет.

**Обособление факультативно,** сравнить: "Большинство из нас уверены, что из них вырастут лишь «дикари», которые при любом уходе не зацветут и не дадут плодов никогда, а в лучшем случае ― через 20-25 лет".

(2) Конечно, у нас есть отдельные примеры создания продуктов мирового уровня, но это, скорее, исключение из правила, это то, что создано не «благодаря», а в большей степени «вопреки». **Практически не обособляется**, кроме особых случаев.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Могут ли наречные выражения "в большей степени" и  "в лучшем случае" быть вводными словами. Справочники уверяют нас, что нет, никогда. **А почему?**

Тематика у них для этого подходящая, оценочная, как, к примеру, у сочетания "по крайне мере". Это сочетания, а их легче обособить, чем отдельные слова. **Поэтому предлагается зачислить их в словарь вводных слов.**

**Примеры**

(1) Однако рекомендации по организации вычислений неотделимы от модификации самих методов вычислений, традиционно продолжающих линию минимизации числа операций (привлекательной на уровне счётчиков-вычислителей, работающих с арифмометром **или, в лучшем случае**, с однопроцессорной ЭВМ 60-х годов).

(2)Так что сейчас музыка бытия еле слышно звучит лишь где-то на задворках его сознания **или, в лучшем случае,** бережно сохраняется избранными служителями в немногих заповедниках, куда очень непросто попасть непросвещённому и непосвящённому…

(3) Мы с ним полгода работали в Америке и каждодневно тесно общались, и он мне тогда откровенно сказал: "Я ведь понимаю, что если бы не кино, то в цирке я бы был, **в лучшем случае,** кандидатом на заслуженного… И. Э. Кио

(4) Вот живёт же одна, ни мужа, ни детей, впереди светит ей, **в лучшем случае**, дом для престарелых актёрок, жизнь доживать. [Г. Я. Бакланов.

(5)В нем преобладала философия ученого, **в большей степени**, чем у Ласкера, который тоже был ученым, но игроком ― в первую очередь.

Comment: >> **Поэтому предлагается зачислить их в словарь вводных слов.** Кому вы предлагаете?

Comment: Это шутка, Niemand, всего лишь шутка, ну почему вы всегда так серьезны.?  А предлагаю я избавиться от жесткого мышления, выраженного  в виде ограниченных суждений-правил. Вводные слова - это всего лишь сочетания определенной тематики, а ведь даже обычные наречия в определенной позиции могут быть обособлены. В "лучшем случае" обособляется не часто, но вот в положении после союза ИЛИ авторы начинают его дружно обособлять.

Comment: _Vera: "(5) В нем преобладала философия ученого, в большей степени, чем у Ласкера, который тоже был ученым, но игроком ― в первую очередь"._  === Гм… Гм… А разве в этом предложении **"в большей степени"** -- вводное? Давайте попробуем его удалить:

_В нем преобладала философия ученого, чем у Ласкера…_  **(???)**

Comment: "В большей степени, чем у Ласкера" - это распространенное сочетание, но обособление факультативное, да еще сомнительное. А если так: "Но в нем, в большей степени,  всегда преобладала философия ученого..."  Здесь будем обособлять?

Comment: "В большей степени преобладала" — это ой.

Comment: А как вы оформите ту же мысль красиво и правильно, без "ой" и желательно так же кратко.

Answer (score 3):

Ни ""в большей степени", ни "в лучшем случае"  не являются вводными и не выделяются запятыми. Это наречные выражения.

> См.: Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010.
>
> Словарь синонимов ASIS. В.Н. Тришин. 2013.